# SVM with Dynamic Time Warping kernel

Tags: svm, dtw

I need to use Support Vector Machine (SVM) classifier with a Dynamic Time Warping (DTW) kernel for some audio processing task. All the tools I know (Weka, LibSVM, SKLearn) have SVMs with standard kernels (linear, poly, RBF) only. Where can I find a SVM tool/library with DTW kernel?